# i18next - Loading translations from a JSON file

Tags: node.js, json, typescript, i18next

I'm trying to load translations from a JSON file using i18next library on Node. The path of the JSON file points to the correct location.

I'm getting the following error:
`i18next::translator: missingKey en translation test test`

```
import i18next from 'i18next';
import Backend from 'i18next-fs-backend';

const instance = i18next.use(Backend).createInstance({
    lng: config.language,
    debug: true,
    fallbackLng: 'en',
    initImmediate: false,
    backend: {
        loadPath: join(__dirname, `${config.language}.json`),
    },
}, (error, t) => {
    console.log(t('foo'));
});
```

JSON file:

```
{
      "foo": "bar"
}
```

Specifying the translations directly in `createInstance` using `resources` property works perfectly.

I tried everything I could think of, with no success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution!

```
import i18next from 'i18next';
import Backend from 'i18next-fs-backend';

const instance = i18next.use(Backend).createInstance();
instance.init({
    lng: config.language,
    debug: true,
    fallbackLng: 'en',
    initImmediate: false,
    backend: {
        loadPath: join(__dirname, `${config.language}.json`),
    },
}, (error, t) => {
    console.log(t('foo'));
});
```